# How to plot the following region with bold ribs?

Tags: plotting, regions

Consider the following region:

```
h1 = -19.48 - 5;
h2 = 25.78;
xminIni = -1.25;
\[CapitalDelta]xIni = 2.5;
yminIni = -2.5;
\[CapitalDelta]yIni = 5;
xminFin = -2.5;
\[CapitalDelta]xFin = 5;
yminFin = -5;
\[CapitalDelta]yFin = 10.;
p1 = Pyramid[{{xminFin, yminFin, h2}, {xminFin, 
     yminFin + \[CapitalDelta]yFin, 
     h2}, {xminFin + \[CapitalDelta]xFin, 
     yminFin + \[CapitalDelta]yFin, 
     h2}, {xminFin + \[CapitalDelta]xFin, yminFin, h2}, {0, 0, -70.}}];
N[1/(\[CapitalDelta]yIni*\[CapitalDelta]xIni)
   RegionMeasure[
   RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{xminIni, yminIni, h1}, {xminIni, 
       yminIni + \[CapitalDelta]yIni, 
       h1}, {xminIni + \[CapitalDelta]xIni, 
       yminIni + \[CapitalDelta]yIni, 
       h1}, {xminIni + \[CapitalDelta]xIni, yminIni, h1}}], p1]]]
Region[RegionIntersection[
   Polygon[{{xminIni, yminIni, h1}, {xminIni, 
      yminIni + \[CapitalDelta]yIni, 
      h1}, {xminIni + \[CapitalDelta]xIni, 
      yminIni + \[CapitalDelta]yIni, 
      h1}, {xminIni + \[CapitalDelta]xIni, yminIni, h1}}], p1]];
RegionQ /@ {p1, 
   Cuboid[{xminFin, yminFin, h1}, {xminFin + \[CapitalDelta]xFin, 
     yminFin + \[CapitalDelta]yFin, h2}]};
DecayVolume = 
  RegionIntersection[p1, 
   Cuboid[{xminFin, yminFin, h1}, {xminFin + \[CapitalDelta]xFin, 
     yminFin + \[CapitalDelta]yFin, h2}]];
```

It may be plotted:

```
Region[Style[DecayVolume, Opacity[0.1]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

However, I would like to plot it with bold ribs:

[image]

Could you please show how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with a `Region`, but with a [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion.html) you can supply different styles to the 1-, 2-, and 3-dimensional cells using the [`MeshCellStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html) option:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[DecayVolume,
    MeshCellStyle -> {
        1 -> Directive[Thick, Red],
        2 -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Interpreter["Color"]["aqua"]]
    },
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
HighlightMesh[DecayVolume, 1, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

```
HighlightMesh[DecayVolume, {Style[1, Directive[Thick, Black]], 
  Style[2, Opacity[.2]]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
r1 = Region[Style[DecayVolume, Opacity[0.1]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
Show[r1, Graphics3D[{Black, Thick, MeshPrimitives[DecayVolume, 1]}]]
```

[image]